# Why can't I add a new pair into a SortedDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, sorteddictionary

I have this `SortedDictionary`:

```
var signature_parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>
{
    { "oauth_callback", SocialEngine.twitter_aggrega_redirect_uri },
    { "oauth_consumer_key", SocialEngine.twitter_aggrega_consumer_key },
};
```

now I tried this:

```
var header_parameters = signature_parameters.Add("oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature));
```

but it says `I can't assign a void variable to a implicit method`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What would you like to assign to `header_parameters`? A new dictionary?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I assume he wants to have the `KeyValuePair<string,string>` of the last inserted item. (_"Why can't I add a new pair..."_)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Others assume he wants a new dictionary with that item added. Hence my question. I don't like assumptions.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: I don't like `var` in this case. But method chaining is a known pattern. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119799/method-chaining-in-c-sharp Also, markzzz is a fan of `KeyValuePairs` http://stackoverflow.com/q/19251781/284240 ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know it is, but there are still assumptions about what is being returned to be chained. Now there is an accepted answer I suppose we know what was wanted :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where am I wrong?

You're calling the `Add` method, but expecting it to return something. It doesn't.

If you're trying to create a *new* dictionary with the same entries and one new one, you probably want:

```
var headerParameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(signatureParameters)
{
    "oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature)
};
```

The constructor will create a copy of the existing dictionary, then the collection initializer will add the key/value pair just to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

`Add` method adds item to dictionary, but returns nothing, so you can't assign result of `Add` method to variable.

```
signature_parameters.Add("oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature))
```

You can assign it later, but because it is a reference type, you'll just copy the reference.

```
var header_parameters = signature_parameters;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7620520y.aspx) is a void method since it adds an item to the dictionary but it does not return something.

So change this

```
var header_parameters = signature_parameters.Add("oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature));
```

to

```
var header_parameters = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("oauth_signature", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature));
signature_parameters.Add(header_parameters.Key, header_parameters.Value);
```

( assuming that you want to have the last inserted `KeyValuePair` )